# ERRAI CDI in the browser

Tags: java, gwt, cdi, ioc-container, errai

Errai is a GWT library that ,among other things, implements CDI.

Usuallly CDI API is implemented by an IOC container,
Can you help to understand how a GWT library can implement it on client side, i.e. on the browser ?

I'm really having hard time making sense of it.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? An IOC container can also be implemented in JavaScript.

Comment: maybe it's just this that I don't getis Errai a kind of Ioc container for gwt classes ?

Comment: also on server side an  IOC container makes extensive use of reflection, in js ther's no such a concept I think..

Answer (score 0):

Errai implements dependency injection by generating java code for it. Basically some code that provides manual reflection/instantiation.

If you have a project you can look at the java code in 
"target.generated\org\jboss\errai\ioc\client"